# Replace string with the same start and end in notepad++

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

Not much of a expert in regular expression here. My IT colleague dump my a text file which containt all our mailing list. But I need to clean it before using it.

I need to find and delete a string of text which always start by "3EA" and finish by "////".

I try several ways, but no cigars.

Here's some example of the string I need to delete :

```
3AEAEACjkCjm////
3AEAEACjlCjn////
3AEAEACjnCjp////
```

Thanks

Comment: please share (more complete) sample input and current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
3AE[a-zA-Z]{9}/{4}
```

Try  this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/61

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex,

```
3EA\S*?////
```

Add anchors if necessary.

```
^3EA\S*?////$
```

Comment: or `^3EA\S*?\/\/\/\/$`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are always 9 alphabetical characters in between `3AE` and `////`, in search and replace (in regex mode) replace this pattern with a blank pattern:

```
3AE[A-Za-z]{9}////
```